# Data frame creating observations instead of variable

Tags: r

I have a strange problem in R.
I would like to create a data frame with two variables but instead it gives me just one variable with a lot of observations.

In the following example the first data frame is correct and gives three variables, but the second only one.
Why is that and how can I change it?

Thanks

```
t1 <- c(1:5)
t2 <- c(1:5)
t3 <- c(1:5)
test.data <- data.frame(t1, t2, t3)
str(plot.data) 
#Three variables are in the data frame.


one <- c(1:5)
two <- c(1:15)
three <- c(1:10)

plot.data <- data.frame("id"=rbind(
c(
  rep(1,times = length(one)),
  rep(2,times = length(two)),
  rep(3,times = length(three)))), "obs"=
  rbind(c(one, two, three))
)
str(plot.data)
#There is only one variable in the data frame, but there should be two (id and obs)!
```

Comment: You don't need `rbind`, just `c` is enough. If you ditch the `rbind`, you will get a data.frame with two variables `id` and `obs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `rbind`, you are getting a data structure that requires you to call `x` and `y` differently to get just the values:

```
> x <- rbind(
  c(
    rep(1,times = length(one)),
    rep(2,times = length(two)),
    rep(3,times = length(three))))
> y <- (rbind(c(one, two, three)))
> str(x)
 num [1, 1:30] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
> str(y)
 int [1, 1:30] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
```

To get to just the values (for contrast, just type `x` and compare):

```
> x[,]
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
> y[,]
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

So create data frame like this:

```
> df <- data.frame(x=x[,],y=y[,])
> df
   x  y
1  1  1
2  1  2
3  1  3
4  1  4
5  1  5
6  2  1
7  2  2
```